# Select box values in PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, select, for-loop

I have a select box like this. This is nothing but looping from 1 to 10.

```
  <select name="author_box[]" id="author_box[]">
    <?php for($j=1;$j<=10;$j++){ ?>
        <option id="<?php echo $j; ?>" name="<?php echo $j; ?>" value="<?php echo $$j; ?>"><?php echo $j; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

For example: I have a variable $tmp_rating="5". So what I want to display is showing the value 5 in the select box along with the other values (i.e. from 1 to 10).

How can I achieve that. In short, the value which I fetch from the database should be displayed first in the select box.

Thank you gentleman, for all the time and instant reply. This portal helps me a lot in fixing my issues in less time.

Comment: It would even be faster if you learned how to use search engines...

Comment: yup, i do understand. But i have stated very well that I'm new to coding. So forgive me and never down vote anyone and it hurtz ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding this condition

```
<?php if($j == $tmp_rating) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>
```

Full code

```
<option <?php if($j == $tmp_rating) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> id="<?php echo $j; ?>" name="<?php echo $j; ?>" value="<?php echo $$j; ?>"><?php echo $j; ?></option>
```

Comment: Excellent. Where you people are sitting and giving me instant answers. great !! worked fine. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the `selected` attribute for the `option`:

```
<select name="author_box[]" id="author_box[]">
    <?php for($j=1;$j<=10;$j++){ ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $j; ?>" <?=($tmp_rating==$j)?'selected="selected"':null;?>><?php echo $j; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

This way, if `$tmp_rating` is the same as `$j` in your loop, the attribute `selected` is added and the correct value displays in your selectbox.